# How can I modify my code to output both percentages and numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the code below that analyzes data in an excel sheet to produce a count of each fruit. I am looking to modify the code so I have another column with a relative percentage of each fruit or if there is a way I can write a code to reference the output from the code below to provide the needed percentage.

```
fruit = active["basket"].str.split(";").apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()

fruit = fruit.str.strip()
fruit = fruit.str.strip('#')
fruit.index = fruit.index.droplevel(-1)
fruit.name = "basket"
del active["basket"]
fruit = active.join(fruit)
fruit.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name = 'FRUIT_List', index = False)

fruit_counts = fruit.groupby(["basket"]).size().reset_index()
fruit_counts.rename(columns = {0: "Count"},inplace = True)
fruit_counts.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name = 'FRUIT_Counts', index = False)

print(fruit_counts)
```

Output:

```
Basket     Count
Oranges     9
Mangoes     8
Watermelons 6
Sugarcanes  5
Grapes      3
```

Comment: Thank you @martineau, I tried print(df.groupby('bun').count()) on the output and couldn't get the desired outcome

Comment: Please, update your question with further descriptions, code snippets of what you tried and what was the result, and why that is not what you want.

Comment: Furthermore, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to setup a minimal reproducible example for people to engage with your question and being able to run and test both the faulty program as well as proposed solutions.

Comment: I'm not a pandas/dataframe expert, but it sounds to me like you want to add a column to one based upon what's in anther (column) — so I suggest you do some research into how to accomplish something like that. [Here's some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bdataframe%5D+add+column) related to the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a percentage column to fruit_counts dataframe:

```py
fruit_counts['percent'] = fruit_counts.Count / fruit_counts['Count'].sum()
```

Output:

```
    Basket      Count   percent
0   Oranges     9   0.290323
1   Mangoes     8   0.258065
2   Watermelons 6   0.193548
3   Sugarcanes  5   0.161290
4   Grapes      3   0.096774
```

Comment: Thank you @CFfreitas This worked!